# Vinculación de una tabla que se tiene en un libro dentro de una de hoja de cálculo a un objeto de imagen

Tags: vba

Hola equipo espero se encuentren muy bien, les escribe Hernán Martínez, por medio de la presente necesito pedírles el favor de indicarmen como puedo asignar los datos
de una hoja a una imagen utilizando el lenguaje de programacion para macros VBA, es que en el nuevo empleo que tengo una de las aplicaciones en las que debo de trabajar
veo que a un componente de Imagen que esta dentro de una hoja en Excel se le asigna el valor de una tabla que esta dentro de otra hoja del mismo libro, pero todo esto
lo hacen asignando los valores en el editor de ecuaciones, necesito hacer este proceso pero utilizando VBA .

Espero haberme explicado adecuadamente

Muchas gracias.
Espero haberme explicado bien

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Para poder recibir ayuda yo opino que necesitas darnos más datos, algo de código, nos muestres la imagen que se genera y si ya existe alguna ecuación que genera una imagen la pongas para analizar y poder apoyar

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es el comando cámara:

> [Mostrar dinámicamente el contenido de una celda o rango en un objeto
> gráfico](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/mostrar-din%C3%A1micamente-el-contenido-de-una-celda-o-rango-en-un-objeto-gr%C3%A1fico-e2e7a629-5662-42d6-9295-06d112c2099f)

El último apartado, que tiene título **Mostrar dinámicamente el contenido del rango de celdas en una imagen**

Básicamente crea una imagen en un sitio basándose en celdas de otro. **Muy útil para que algunas personas no toquen lo que no deben** y para **no complicarse con los márgenes**, ya que la imagen no cambia de tamaño y el contenido se ajusta solo en tamaño (si pones muchos datos no se verá nada).

Un ejemplo: Tengo una tabla de datos falsa generada en mockaroo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo de la izquierda son celdas normales y lo de la derecha es una imagen vinculada a ese rango de celdas. Aunque cambie el rango, la imagen no cambiará de tamaño, salvo que yo lo haga. Por eso es muy útil para informes y tenerlo todo ya cuadrado y que imprima todo bien. Mira que pasa si añado más datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tamaño de la imagen no ha cambiado. Excel solo ha autoajustado todo. Pero ten cuidado porque si son muchas filas, no se verá nada bien, como en mi imagen.

Juega un poco con ello y verás que no tiene ningún misterio. No te pongo código VBA porque si no sabes usarlo a mano con VBA te explotará la cabeza. Pero puedes usar el grabador de macros para ver el código :)